# Regex substitute multiple patterns with corresponding replacement patterns

Tags: python, regex

```py
tokens = ['analytics', 'mining', 'quantities', ...]
for i in tokens:
    stem = re.sub(r'(\w+)(tics$)', r'\1sis', i, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

In this example, I'm replacing 'analytics' with 'analysis' using the re.sub().
What I want to do is to do this replacement using multiple patterns, for example:

```py
stem = re.sub(r'(\w+)(ing$)', r'\1e', i, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

So that 'mining' would be replaced by 'mine'. And so on.

I was thinking of using a dict with patterns and repls. I imagine the dict would look something like this:

```py
rules = {
        r'(\w+)(tics$)': r'\1sis',
        r'(\w+)(ing$)': r'\1e',
        ...
}
```

Would the backreference even work in a dict? I also don't know how to implement a dict into re.sub. How should I proceed?

Edit for further clarification:

The whole tokens list has a lot of items and I want to do the replacement on words that match the pattern. For example there might be the word 'dining' further down in the tokens and I want to the the second rule to catch that and replace it with 'dine'.

Comment: If there is `hitting`, would you still want to get `hitte`? Use an NLP package.

Comment: I'm trying to make my own basic stemmer and then compare to Porter/Lancaster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a custom function in `re.sub`

**Ex:**

```
import re

tokens = ['analytics', 'mining', 'quantities', 'analyticsddd']
replacement = {"tics": "sis", "ing": "e"}
ptrn = re.compile("(" + "|".join(replacement.keys()) + ")$")

for i in tokens:
    print(ptrn.sub(lambda x: replacement.get(x.group(), x.group()), i))
```

**Output:**

```
analysis
mine
quantities
analyticsddd
```